# SessionIDs are not unique in PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm learning on how to do session management on PHP and trying to allow only one login session by using `session_id()` to generate login session hash, but it seems that something is wrong, because each time i call out `session_id()` i will be returned the same hash `0b055b4f53310060d84535ee8e3bf663`. I tried logging in with multiple users, it's returning same hash for each login session and for each user.

```
//Login.php:
session_start(); // Starting Session
//Take inputs, do user query
if (queryResultRows == 1){
    $_SESSION['userid']=$userinfo["uid"];
    $_SESSION['userlevel']=$userinfo["userlevel"];
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
    $sessionid = session_id();
    //Insert sessionId into DB..
    //Redirect to next page.
}
//Logout.php:
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) // Destroying All Sessions
{
    header("Location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
```

Now i tried to do login, i successfully had access to all session restricted areas on my page (session was created and is working) then initated logout.php, the session was destroyed, i had no longer access, did login again, but the `session_id()` value was still the same. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_destroy()` only delete the data of the session and don't delete the attached cookie.

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session.
>   In order to kill the session altogether, the session ID must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session ID (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

[Documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

You can also regenerate a new session_id with [`session_regenerate_id`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)

[More information about PHP sessions and cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6253698/7325328)

Comment: So overwriting sessionId cookie would do it?

Comment: Following the given information, I guess you should use `session_regenerate_id()` after your `session_destroy()` or unset the session cookie with `setcookie()` because :
_use of session_regenerate_id() will also submit a new session cookie with the new session id._ [Source](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)