# Stopping a submit when a request fake request is sent to the backend

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, backend

My issue that I encountered here is when I send a request with parameters to my PHP back-end it would act as a form was submitted and would send a false submission. I use AJAX to communicate with the front and back-end and the code I use is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitmsg").click(function () {
        var usrmsg = $("#Text").val();
        var username = localStorage.getItem("user")
        $.post("send.php", { text: usrmsg,user: username,},
            function(result){ });
        $("#Text").val("");
        return false;
   });
});
```

in my backend where it gets the request is

```
$username = $_POST['user']; 
$text = $_POST['text'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will prevent Cross-Site Scripting

When your page loads, save a token in a session / cookie / database.

```
$_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
```

In your AJAX call pass that same token to send.php:

```
{ text: usrmsg,user: username, token: token_generated }
```

In send.php just check the tokens match

```
if ($_POST['token'] != $_SESSION['token']) exit();
```

Or if your only concert are fake submits try a captcha.

Also you can validate the fields using Javascript BEFORE they're send via AJAX.

Comment: how would I make this into a cookie? would I use echo

Comment: To set browser cookies you use setcookie() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Then the cookie will be available on $_COOKIE['name_of_cookie'].

I would use $_SESSION for this purpose anyway, you can find differences and reasons here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253633/cookies-vs-sessions

Comment: Thanks! When I use the same code as you and I add the if sentence in send.php the process just dies. The token gets sent to the backend (according to DevTools). How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post here the the code for send.php so I can have a quick look.

Comment: I meant the whole thing, to see how you are processing the token, etc.

Comment: $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

$fp = fopen('chatlog.html', 'a');

 fwrite($fp,$message); @kissumisha

Comment: I found the problem. Only the POST request variable gets set but the other one doesn't

Comment: What do you mean with "the other one"? Do you mean the SESSION is not being started?

Comment: My session is started. But I can not access it in the send.php

Comment: But I can access the $_SESSION in index.php

Comment: Probably sounds like obvious, but did you start the session also in send.php so the SESSION variables can be accessed?

Comment: I started the session  in index.php

Comment: In order to access the SESSION variables from another script, you will need to start the session there too. So add session_start() to send.php and you will be able to use the $_SESSION that are stored.